# How to vertically center included pdfs?

Tags: vertical-alignment, pdfpages

when I'm trying to fill a poster with multiple (landscape) slides, like this:

```
\documentclass[a0]{sciposter}

% Support for PDF inclusion
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

  \includepdf[pages=27-34,nup= 2x8,noautoscale,scale=2]{english.pdf}

\end{document}
```

the resulting 'figure' starts in the middle of the page going upwards outside of the page.
How can I set it to be vertically centered?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @ScottH that you can use `offset`. But you are trying to use only 8 pages from `27-34`. But you are using a `nup=2x8`. That means you are trying to print 2 rows with 8 pages in each row. That is the mistake. It should be `nup=2x4`. Then you are in business again.

In addition to `offset`, you can use `delta= delx dely` to fine tune the page you are printing (Refer page 9, figure 1 of the pdfpages manual -- `texdoc pdfpages` from terminal). A little example:

```
\documentclass[a0]{sciposter}
%% Support for PDF inclusion
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
%
\begin{document}
%
\includepdf[pages=1-8,nup=2x4,landscape,offset=-2ex 5ex,delta=-10ex -10ex]{infthesis.pdf}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used negative values in `delta=-10ex -10ex` as my pdf (infthesis) had a large margin. You may adjust it suitably for your file.